# Plotting margin plots for geom_ raster() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am trying to plot a raster map with some data, and margin plots of this data.
Kind of like the `levelplot()` `rasterVis` function, or even better with colors (reflecting the colors inside the plot) instead than with a line. It will be clear below, looking at what I'm trying to do. `rasterVis` example (with density line):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiaUu.png]

However, I want to use ggplot2. Download the [data used in this example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxlZ3Tjj36sNajJQcndPOFhYWDQ) (8KB).

I tried to use `grid.arrange()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(grid)
library(scales) #for muted()
library(gridExtra)

load("example.Rsave") #load data

#prepare data for the margin plot
var=tp_rlim; min=0; max=1; mid=0.5
varname <- colnames(var)[3]
zonal <- aggregate(var[,3], list(var$Lat), mean)
colnames(zonal) <- c("Lat", varname)

#plot the margin plot
ggzonal <- ggplot(zonal, aes(x="", y=Lat, fill=tp))+ 
             geom_raster() +
             theme(legend.position="none",
                   axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                   axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                   axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                   axis.text.y = element_blank()
                   ) +
             scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(min, max), space="Lab", midpoint=mid)

#plot main plot
  gg <- ggplot(var, aes_string(x="Lon", y="Lat", fill=varname)) +
          geom_raster() +
          coord_quickmap(xlim = range(var$Lon), ylim = range(var$Lat)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(min, max), space="Lab", midpoint=mid) +
            theme(legend.position="bottom",
                  legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"),
                  legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "cm"),
                  legend.title=element_blank()
                  ) + 
            borders(region=unique(na.omit(map.where("world", var$Lon, var$Lat))), colour="black")

  grid.arrange(gg, ggzonal, ncol=2, widths=c(5, 1))
```

But the outcome is unsatisfactory:
[image]

I have also tried to use `ggExtra::ggMarginal`, but:

```
ggExtra::ggMarginal(gg)
```

[image]

Or:

```
ggExtra::ggMarginal(gg, type="histogram")
```

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might work,

```
# fix the ylim of annotation plot
gg2 = ggzonal + coord_cartesian(ylim = range(var$Lat)) 
# devtools::install_github("baptiste/egg")
library(egg)
ggarrange(gg, gg2, widths = c(10,1))
```

[image]

Comment: However, you see the right column is slightly, slighly shorter? I am a perfectionist, unfortunately, and cannot make do with that :(

Comment: the panel has the right size, so I think there's something wrong with the data in that plot.

Comment: indeed, the RHS plot didn't have the same y limits as the other one

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works very well, I should have thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the wonderful `cowplot` package and the instruction found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html), we can do the following:

```
library(cowplot)

grobs <- ggplotGrob(gg + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
legend_b <- grobs[[which(sapply(grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]

prow <- plot_grid(gg + theme(legend.position="none"), ggzonal, align = 'h', rel_widths = c(5, 1))

plot_grid(prow, legend_b, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, .2))
ggsave('stack.png', w = 5, h = 5)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have a question tho. In your answer, if I set `rel_widths = c(10, 1)` instead of `rel_widths = c(5, 1)`, the right plot gest compressed a little. Why is that? It's too wide the way it is now. EDIT: ok, I also have to divide rel_heights accordingluy, although that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: One small niggle: using this approach cancels the coord_quickmap(), resorting to coord_equal() apparently. Can I do something to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know!